# Mirror Drivers not working on Windows 7 64 bit computer

Tags: windows, memory-management, graphics, windows-7, driver

I am trying to develop an application that uses a mirror driver, although I am having an issue getting **any** mirror driver to work properly on my computer. I always seem to get the same issue no matter which driver I user. I have tried the Mirror Driver in UltraVNC and Also the DemoForge Mirage Driver that is included in TightVNC.

These are the issues I seem to receive- this this the issue from DemoForge Mirage. The error from the other drivers are essentially the same just maybe worded slightly different:

```
Could not create device driver context!
Unable to map memory for mirror driver!
```

Considering this is happening with all mirror drivers I am thinking maybe it is an issue with my graphics card or Intel HD graphics.

My display adapters are:

```
Nvidia GeForce GT525M
Intel HD Graphics 3000
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem could be and how to fix it? I have thought about just developing on another computer but it doesn't change the fact that I am still having an issue and others will too.

Comment: Maybe a admin/right/security issue?

Comment: I tried running elevated and still the same problems. Is there something else I could try?

Comment: "Note that the handle to the DC can only **be used by a single thread at any one time**." ... Make sure that you have ended every application that could assume hold of such handle (VNCs, TeamViewer (?), Skype (?), Avast (?) - basically any app capable of remote controlling). Also note that I think (pure speculation) that there is a chance of you having a virus spying on your screen using this handle.